# Finding the best match using metaprogramming technique

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am investigating the best match algorithm whitch is represented in Template, the Complete Guide
The implementation  is  the following

```
template<typename List>
class FrontT;

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
class FrontT<Typelist<Head, Tail...>>
{
 public:
  using Type = Head;
};

template<typename List>
using Front = typename FrontT<List>::Type;
 template<typename List>
class PopFrontT;

template<typename Head, typename... Tail>
class PopFrontT<Typelist<Head, Tail...>> {
 public:
  using Type = Typelist<Tail...>;
};

template<typename List>
using PopFront = typename PopFrontT<List>::Type;
template<typename List>
class LargestTypeT;

// recursive case:
template<typename List>
class LargestTypeT
{
 private:
  using First = Front<List>;
  using Rest = typename LargestTypeT<PopFront<List>>::Type;
 public:
  using Type = IfThenElse<(sizeof(First) >= sizeof(Rest)), First, Rest>;
};

// basis case:
template<>
class LargestTypeT<Typelist<>>
{
 public:
  using Type = char;
};

template<typename List>
using LargestType = typename LargestTypeT<List>::Type;
```

That I hard understand is the following line

```
using Type = IfThenElse<(sizeof(First) >= sizeof(Rest)), First, Rest>;
```

It is clear that the `First` is the First Element in `TypeList` and `sizeof` it is the size of this type. But I confused with the `Rest`. What is the size of `Rest`? The `Rest` it is a list with the rest of the elements that are included in typelist.

For example, if the following is defined

```
LargestType<TypeList<int,bool,char>>
```

In the first loop
`First` is `int` and `sizeof` is 4
`Rest` is `bool,char` , what is the `sizeof` ?
In the second loop
`First` is `bool` and `sizeof` is 1
`Rest` is `char` and `sizeof` is 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the size of Rest? The Rest it is a list with the rest of the elements that are included in typelist.

No, `Rest` (which is a bit poorly named) is actually not the rest of the list, but rather the largest type in the rest of the list, as you can see from its definition:

```
using Rest = typename LargestTypeT<PopFront<List>>::Type;
```

Comment: But In first recursion , the Rest = LargestTypeT<bool, char>::Type . Is this right?And recursively  the LargestTypeT is called again . My question in the fist loop how the IfThenElse statememt is evaluated?

Comment: `LargestTypeT<bool, char>::Type` is `bool`. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

> I confused with the Rest. What is the size of Rest? The Rest it is a list with the rest of the elements that are included in typelist.

Look at the definition of `Rest`

```
using Rest = typename LargestTypeT<PopFront<List>>::Type;
```

`Rest` is the largest type in `List`, excluding (`PopFront`) the first type (`First`).

> In the first loop First is int and sizeof is 4 Rest is bool,char , what is the sizeof ? In the second loop First is bool and sizeof is 1 Rest is char and sizeof is 1

Not exactly.

In first loop, `First` is `int`, `Rest` is `bool`.

In second loop (where `Rest` for first loop is selected as `bool`) `First` is `bool` and `Rest` is `char`.

In third loop (where `Rest` for second loop is selected as `char`) `First` is `char` and `Rest` is `char`.

In fourth loop you have the ground case (or basic case, as you prefer)

```
template<>
class LargestTypeT<Typelist<>>
{
 public:
  using Type = char;
};
```

that select the `Type` (the `Rest` in third loop) as `char`

Comment: Why in the first loop the Rest is bool. I have the impression that the LargestType will be called until all elements removed. In the final  step the int will be compared with char. I have not undestood how the algorithm works.

Comment: @getsoubl - in first loop `Rest` is `bool` because in second loop `First` is `bool` and `Rest` is `char` so `sizeof(First)` is equal to `sizeof(Rest)` (both are 1) so `sizeof(First) >= sizeof(Rest)` is `true` so in `using Type = IfThenElse<(sizeof(First) >= sizeof(Rest)), First, Rest>;` `First` (`bool`) is selected.